# AngularJS filter bu option/select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Source: https://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/nCfAj

I am new to angularJS and am trying to get my head around it.

I have a task where I need to filter a select option menu and display only the items in a category. I found this online (below) and it's a good start. However I can't work out how make it filter by each option 'catgry'. Eventually I would like to filter and display by: 'title/name', 'run', 'swim' and other. With only the selected category visible. I appreciate any help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Anjular Filtered List</title>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>

img{
width:300px;
height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="notebooks" ng-app="notebooks" ng-controller="NotebookListCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query">
  <select ng-model="orderList">
    <option value="title">By title</option>
    <option value="-catgry">Swim</option>
    <option value="catgry">Other</option>
  </select>

  <ul id="notebook_ul">
    <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
      <h3>{{notebook.title}}</h3>
      <img src="{{notebook.featimg}}" alt="">
      <p>{{notebook.ctent}}</p>
      <div class="right top">{{notebook.catgry}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Number of Articles: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
</div>

<script>
var notebooks = angular.module('notebooks', []);

notebooks.controller('NotebookListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.notebooks = [
    {"title": "Making sure you are ready like the Gold Coast for the Commonwealth Games",
     "featimg": "images/image2.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "swim"},
    {"title": "Looking after us on our beaches",
     "featimg": "images/image1.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "run"},
    {"title": "Running is Beautiful",
     "featimg": "images/image3.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "other"},
    {"title": "What swimming stroke is this?",
     "featimg": "images/image4.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "swim"},
    {"title": "Team Dynamics",
     "featimg": "images/image5.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "other"},
    {"title": "Why Quidditch?",
     "featimg": "images/image6.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "run"}
  ];
  $scope.orderList = "title";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: am not getting what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I would like to have a select option menu to filter a list of articles based on their category. So if I select 'swim' from the select drop menu only the articles with the category swim will display.

Comment: same is working I've checked by put your code in plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/btoDSy2vA3SuHDUHKWtz?p=preview

Comment: My apologies but I don't understand what you mean by 'same is working'. My current code orders by category but all categories show. :-)

Comment: do u want select control with options as **"swim, run,other"**

Comment: Hi Aravind, The updated code below sorts correctly by category "swim, run,other". Just need to work out how to have only the selected category showing rather than sorting by:X. :-)

Comment: @TheMechanic Thanks for the help. Could you please explain what this does: ...data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go
Just figure out you should go ahead with `ng-show`, `ng-hide`
for more info [ben nadel](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-filter-vs-nghide-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm)

working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/btoDSy2vA3SuHDUHKWtz?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div id="notebooks" ng-app="notebooks" ng-controller="NotebookListCtrl">

      <select ng-model="orderList">
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="swim">Swim</option>
        <option value="run">Run</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
      {{orderList}}

      <ul id="notebook_ul">
        <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks"
        ng-show="notebook.catgry === orderList">
          <h3>{{notebook.title}} + {{notebook.catgry}}</h3>
          <img src="{{notebook.featimg}}" alt="">
          <p>{{notebook.ctent}}</p>
          <div class="right top">{{notebook.catgry}}</div>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <span>Number of Articles: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var notebooks = angular.module('notebooks', []);

notebooks.controller('NotebookListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.notebooks = [
    {"title": "Making sure you are ready like the Gold Coast for the Commonwealth Games",
     "featimg": "images/image2.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "swim"},
    {"title": "Looking after us on our beaches",
     "featimg": "images/image1.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "run"},
    {"title": "Running is Beautiful",
     "featimg": "images/image3.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "other"},
    {"title": "What swimming stroke is this?",
     "featimg": "images/image4.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "swim"},
    {"title": "Team Dynamics",
     "featimg": "images/image5.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "title"},
    {"title": "Why Quidditch?",
     "featimg": "images/image6.jpg",
     "ctent": "Article intro ang links will be entered into this section.",
     "catgry": "run"}
  ];
  $scope.orderList = "title";
});
```

Comment: This is starting to make sense. Thank you ever so much for sharing your skills.

Comment: I am looking into 'multiple select' options. Reading the Angular documentation you can use' multiple' in the select element as in standard HTML. However filtering like this in all the examples I can find use a button element combined with check boxes. I am trying to get multiple options for the select so if 'run' and 'swim' are selected bot display. At the moment if I use <select id="featuredList" data-ng-model="orderList" multiple name="select"> nothing displays. I understand your time is valuable so appreciate if you've not the time. :-)

Comment: @LaurenceL let's go to chat room so we can discuss further

Comment: my apology for not replying earlier. Mayhem at work. I am in meetings for the next few hours but when convenient with you. I'd appreciate chatting to learn more.